# Cell reusability and row selection in table view in iOS

Tags: iphone, uitableview, customization

I have to create table view with row and section combination, and row of section I customized with button.

Now task is only one row should be selected in each section after tapping on button,

My work of code is given blow, and issues coiming is

1. while tapping on one button of particular section row other section row buttonshowing selection with this, i think cell reusebility problem .
2. How to perform the deselction process for the rest button of same section when i tap on particular button .

Here is my code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    self.juju=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSArray *listSeprately = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"questionid==%d",indexPath.section+1];

    listSeprately = [self.questAnswer filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    self.buttonMe=[[UIButton alloc]init];
    self.buttonMe = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [self.buttonMe setFrame:CGRectMake(260.0, 7.0, 30.0, 30.0)];

    self.buttonMe.tag=i;

    if([[arrayCheckUnchek objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Uncheck"])
    {
        [self.buttonMe setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check.gif"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.buttonMe setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    [self.buttonMe addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    cell.textLabel.text=[juju objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell.contentView addSubview: self.buttonMe];

    i++;

    return cell;
}
```

This code call as we click on any button.

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    CGPoint touchPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView ];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPoint];

    // No need to use tag sender will keep the reference of clicked button

    self.buttonMe = (UIButton *)sender;

    //Checking the condition button is checked or unchecked.
    //accordingly replace the array object and change the button image

    if([[arrayCheckUnchek objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Uncheck"])
    {
        [ self.buttonMe setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkImage.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [arrayCheckUnchek replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"Check"];
    }
    else
    {
        [ self.buttonMe setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.jpg"]   forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [arrayCheckUnchek replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"Uncheck"];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.arrayCheckUnchek = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.questAnswer=//here i hve records store that is 19

    for(int i=0; i<[self.questAnswer count]; i++)
    {
        [arrayCheckUnchek addObject:@"Uncheck"];
    }
}
```

It's showing my check box, showing multiple selection for all rows. Selecting any cell automatically it's selecting other also .

Comment: why ur use   i++;? tableview automatcally increment  no need use i++?

Comment: got a solution or not ?

Comment: U have use worst formatting. I have edit as much I can. Please Check spelling and grammer so someone can understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the index ([indexPath row]) in a value under didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method. Then you can check if the [indexPath row] is equal to you value under before you return in cellForRowAtIndexPath: method. A block such as The following can be added after you make the check;

```
if (match) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: i have not added the checkmark for selection, i added the button, this will not wrking for